# How to loop a line of values using ',' and the print it as a list

Tags: shell, ksh, cat, cut, for

I'm trying to loop a file using a delimiter with a ',' and the print out those values in a "list" but I'm not sure how to get all the values of delimiter.

I have a file with emails like this (all in one line):

`test1@mail.com,test2@mail.com,test3@mail.com`

and my script is like this:

```
EmailsFile="/dev/fs/C/Users/myuser/Desktop/EMAILSTOREAD.txt"

for email in $(cat ${EmailsFile} | cut -d "," -f 1-100)
do
   echo "${email}\n"
done
```

I did 1-100 due I'm not sure how many values could have the file.

the output that I'm getting is:

`test1@mail.com,test2@mail.com,test3@mail.com`

Expected output:

```
test1@mail.com
test2@mail.com
test3@mail.com
```

Any idea?

Comment: does `</dev/fs/C/Users/myuser/Desktop/EMAILSTOREAD.txt tr ',' '\n'` work for you?

Comment: didn't worked, it worked with the answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is:

```
awk '{ gsub(",","\n"); print $0 }' $EmailsFile
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `tr` which I prefer because it is in the `coreutils` package.

```
tr ',' '\n' < ${EmailsFile}
```